# Trouble finding all palindromes

Tags: python, python-3.x, palindrome

I'm trying to write a program that finds all palindromes within a DNA sequence using Python 3.6. I already have a working function that checks whether a sequence of DNA is a palindrome (which is a little different from a word palindrome) , but I can't seem to get the function that should return all palindromes from the DNA sequence to work. Right now, it only returns a list when the DNA sequence in total is a palindrome, but not the palindromes within the DNA sequence.

Just in case: the function to check whether a sequence is a palindrome (which works fine):

```
def checkPalindrome(DNA):
    converter = DNA.maketrans("ATGC", "TACG")  # finds the complementary strand
    complementary_strand = DNA.translate(converter)

      # reverses the complementary strand
    palindrome_check = complementary_strand[::-1] 
    if strand == palindrome_check:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

And the function that should find all palindromes + the execution code (which doesn't work):

```
def allPalindromes(DNA):
    left,right = 0,len(DNA)
    j = right
    palindromes = []

    while left < right - 1:
        temp = DNA[left:j]
        j -= 1

        if checkPalindrome(temp):
            palindromes.append(temp)

        if j < left+2:
            left += 1
            j = right

    return list(set(palindromes))

strand = getInput()
all_palindromes = allPalindromes(strand)
print(all_palindromes)
```

Comment: There is a bug in your `checkPalindrome` function. It doesn't know what `strand` is. Or is that a global variable?

Comment: That was it! Thanks! I can't believe I made such a stupid mistake.

Comment: Not sure what editor you use, but an editor like PyCharm immediately high-lights errors like these.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! The course I'm doing advised Spyder, but I'm not overly fond of it, so I'll give PyCharm a go.

Comment: PyCharm Community 2017 edition is free and really great. Worth a try indeed.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple labelling error I think. In the second to last line, you have written

```
all_palindromes = allPalindromes(DNA)
```

Whereas this should read

```
all_palindromes = allPalindromes(strand)
```

The DNA is a local parameter within the scope of the function, and so when you get out of the function, it is not defined. Instead strand is the object that you have put your input into, and so should be passed into the function.

Comment: O oops! I'm not sure how it happened, but it must be a typo I made when copying the code to the question, because in the original code I did use strand instead of DNA.